# How to fetch events registered as json from Fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar

I can add events as json to Fullcalendar but I can not get events registered as json from Fullcalendar in a browser.

Please tell me it.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved by myself.

$("#calendar").fullCalendar("clientEvents")